# How to display an image in email in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**Controller**

```
public function index(){
     send_mail('New Volunteer Form received', $this->load->view('site/email/volunteer', NULL, TRUE));
}
```

**Helper Function**

Below helper function and use send email
    function send_mail($subject, $message) {

```
    /* @var $CI CI_Controller  */
    $CI = &get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('upload');
    $CI->load->library('email');
    $CI->email->from('zbc@abc.com', 'Hello');
    $CI->email->to('abc@gmail.com');
    $CI->email->subject($subject);
    $CI->email->message($message);
    $CI->email->set_mailtype('html');
    $CI->email->attach(base_url() . 'uploads/volunteer/');
    return $CI->email->send();
}
```

**View**

```
                    <td>Photo</td>
                    <td style="text-align: center"><img src="<?php base_url() ?>uploads/volunteer/<?php echo $_POST['userfile']; ?>" height="100" width="150"></td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo1.jpg', 'inline');
```

or

```
$message = '<td>Photo</td>';
$message .= '<td style="text-align: center">';
$message .= '<img src="<?php base_url() ?>uploads/volunteer/<?php echo $_POST['."userfile".']; ?>" height="100" width="150">';
$message .= '</td></tr>';
```

> To use the default disposition (attachment), leave the second parameter blank, otherwise use a custom disposition